# how to extract 1st and last non empty value from vector in R?

Tags: r

i have a vector

```
c(NA,13,NA, 12, 15, NA)
```

I need to extract 1st non nan value i.e 13 and last non nan value i.e 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `na.omit` to drop `NA` values and subset the first and last value.

```
x <- c(NA,13,NA, 12, 15, NA)
first_non_NA_value <- na.omit(x)[1]
last_non_NA_value <- rev(na.omit(x))[1]

first_non_NA_value
#[1] 13
last_non_NA_value
#[1] 15
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#first
v[min(which(!is.na(v)))]
[1] 13

#last
v[max(which(!is.na(v)))]
[1] 15

#where v is
v <- c(NA,13,NA, 12, 15, NA)
```